# Having error Raw value for enum case must be a literal

Tags: swift

I am trying to construct a UI element locator strategy for our XCUITests in swift and having troubles with my code snippet. This strategy will be used in all the page classes and will reduce lots of repetitive code in our UI tests.

We are trying to implement a page object model in our tests so we can have a clear implementation of Page structure and the corresponding actions on the page. We have two different apps with the same functionality but the element ID might change on some pages.

e.g, App A's login button's id will be aLoginButton and App B's id will be bLogin button.

I have thought about an implementation which is showed below but having few issues with it.

1. Raw value for enum case must be a literal. I understand enums return value should be string or an integer literal and that raises my question number 2.
2. Am I doing it right ? Is there a better way to do this ?

In the code below, LocatorStrategy will be on it's own file and will serve in the individual page extensions to hold/return UI element location values

P.S I am new to Swift.

```swift
class BasePage {
    func qcom_rcom(qcomId: String , rcomId: String) -> String {
        if QCOM 
          return qcomId
        else 
          return rcomId
    }
}


class LoginPage : BasePage {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print(Locators.menuItemName.identifier)
    }


}

extension LoginPage {
    enum Locators: String, LocatorStrategy {
        case menuItemName = qcom_rcom("aLoginButton", "bLoginButton") // getting error here
    }
}

public protocol LocatorStrategy {
    var identifier: String { get }
}

public extension LocatorStrategy where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {

    var identifier: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}

LoginPage.init()
```

Expected : The enum class case needs to hold two sets of data for the element on a need basis if the UIelement id is different on two different apps. I don't want to create two separate case items aMenuItemName and bMenuItemName to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is `QCOM`? Is it a compile time constant?

Comment: What is unclear with this error message? `qcom_rcom` is a function, not a literal. For example `"aLoginButton"` is a literal. And as you are new to Swift please conform to the naming convention that functions and variables are *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*

Comment: @sweeper yes QCOM is a compile time constant to see which app is being tested and will return the id accordingly . I understand it’s a function but like I mentioned there are times I need to return one string literal or the other based on that app being tested . I thought of calling a method in the case which will do this work for me so I can use single case item itself . I will update my code with camelCase thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use preprocessor directives.

For example,

```
enum Locators: String, LocatorStrategy {
#if QCOM
    case menuItemName = "aLoginButton"
#elseif RCOM
    case menuItemName = "bLoginButton"
#endif
}
```

And then you can change whether it is QCOM or RCOM in your build settings:

[image]